# google form validation using google script

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, radio-button, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I Created a quiz of multiple choice questions using google forms and I used radio buttons for every question.

I want to trigger an event after the form submission with their marks directly sent to email.

For the below code d6 , d7,d8,... are the actual answers .
e.value[6],e.value[7].. are the corresponding values got from form when the form is submitted

When `d6 == e.value[6]` then I have to give 2 marks . This is my Idea.

I got error when validating the above condition using if.

Error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property "6" from undefined. (line 9, file "onFormSubmit")

program:

```
    function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var timestamp = e.values[0];

  var userName = e.values[1];

  var seatNum = e.values[2];

  var yourName = e.values[3];

  var id = e.values[4];

  var email = e.values[5];

  var c=0;
var d6='"john".equals("john")';
var d7='public static void main(String args[])';
var d8='String temp [] = {"a", "b", "c"};';
var d9='void returns no data type.';
var d10='all of the above';
var d11='TRUE';

if(e.value[6].getValue()==d6)
c=c+2;
if(e.value[7].getValue()==d7)
c=c+2;
if(e.value[8].getValue()==d8)
c=c+2;
if(e.value[9].getValue()==d9)
c=c+2;
if(e.value[10].getValue()==d10)
c=c+2;
if(e.value[11].getValue()==d11)
c=c+2;

  var subject = "Fianl Marks ";

  var emailBody = c;

 // var optAdvancedArgs = {name: "Club Ambassador Program", htmlBody: htmlBody};

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject,emailBody);

}
```

Kindly Help me with the above programme, I was sitting on this code for the past 2 days.

Comment: Put a letter "s" on the end of "value".  You have `e.value`.  Should be: `e.values`.

Comment: Thank you sandy . I got the script triggered and working good after modifying `(e.value[10].getvalue()==d10)` to `(e.values[10]==d10)`. This is my output what I am trying to accomplish. [Link](https://vrsecsources.blogspot.com/2016/04/new-java-quiz-real-time-score-to-email.html)